# Add an icon to App Script deployed as web app ("Add to home screen")

Tags: google-apps-script

My app script is deployed as a web app, I used android chrome to **"Add to home screen"** and now I wish to change the default icon (blue G) with my icon

I found in the [chrome developer guide](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) that icons are added using the manifest field "icons".
but it looks like it is not supported as I get the following if I try to add this field

> Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [icons]

Is there a way to add an icon to a deployed web app?
To use an image from my sheet? a file from google drive? and use it in the manifest?

Comment: You can try to refer into my answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135690/how-can-i-update-home-screen-icon-of-my-progressive-web-app). Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen#updating_your_apps_icon_and_name). Also, try the suggested workaround in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

For android, I find that `.setFaviconUrl()`

```html
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlfile').evaluate().setFaviconUrl('exampleLink.com')
```

placed in the `doGet()` function works for setting the icon for adding to the home screen on Android. From my experience the file doesn't have to be .ico, I used a .png in my project.