# Is it possible to add to a web page to the home screen of your phone with a customizable app icon?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react web app where our clients can customize their app icon which should also get displayed on their phone's home screen if they want to add the app to their home screen. Currently it always displays the apps default favicon icon even tho I am overwriting it when the client customizes it. I can also see in the browser tab that i successfully overwrote the favicon. Any ideas how to solve that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about Progressive Web Apps with the add to [home screen feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen) -- might be a duplicate of [How can I update home screen icon of my Progressive Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135690/how-can-i-update-home-screen-icon-of-my-progressive-web-app)